# iPhone Quartz2D render expanding circle

Tags: iphone, graphics, quartz-2d

I'm curious as to the 'proper' method for achieving the following functionality using Quarts2D:

I want to have a view, and to be able to add a circle at any coordinate. As soon as I add the circle it should expand at a predefined rate; I'd also like to repeat this process and have a number if these expanding circles.

Think Missile Command:

[image: Yellow spots keep expanding]

Generally, if I was writing this in C++ using SDL or some other graphics library I would:

Have a class to represent an 'growing circle'
Have a vector/array to hold pointers to all the 'growing circles' I create.

All circles diameters would be increased each tick, and in my renderloop I would iterate the list and draw appropriate circles to my buffer.

This, however, doesn't seem to fit well with how I've generally used views in previous iPhone development.

So I guess it's kind of open-ended, but is there a 'correct' way for something like this?

Would it be in a game loop style (as described above), or should I be subclassing `UIView` for a 'circle' object, and override `drawRect`? I guess I would then have to add each circle by creating a view and adding it to my main view?

Initial investigation also brought me across references to the [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, though I'm guessing this might be much the same as implementing the UIView subclassing technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Add the following code to your UIViewController subclass and you'll get a circle that grows and then fades away wherever you touch:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self addGrowingCircleAtPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view]];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag && [[anim valueForKey:@"name"] isEqual:@"grow"]) {
        // when the grow animation is complete, we fade the layer
        CALayer* lyr = [anim valueForKey:@"layer"];
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.fromValue = [lyr valueForKey:@"opacity"];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.f];
        animation.duration = .5f;
        animation.delegate = self;
        lyr.opacity = 0.f;  
        [animation setValue:@"fade" forKey:@"name"];
        [animation setValue:lyr forKey:@"layer"];
        [lyr addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
    } else if (flag && [[anim valueForKey:@"name"] isEqual:@"fade"]) {
        // when the fade animation is complete, we remove the layer
        CALayer* lyr = [anim valueForKey:@"layer"];
        [lyr removeFromSuperlayer];
        [lyr release];
    }

}

- (void)addGrowingCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    // create a circle path
    CGMutablePathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(circlePath, NULL, 0.f, 0.f, 20.f, 0.f, (float)2.f*M_PI, true);

    // create a shape layer
    CAShapeLayer* lyr = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    lyr.path = circlePath;

    // don't leak, please
    CGPathRelease(circlePath);
    lyr.delegate = self;

    // set up the attributes of the shape layer and add it to our view's layer
    lyr.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    lyr.position = point;
    lyr.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5f, .5f);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:lyr];

    // set up the growing animation
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.fromValue = [lyr valueForKey:@"transform"];
    // this will actually grow the circle into an oval
    CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeScale(6.f, 4.f, 1.f);
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t];
    animation.duration = 2.f;
    animation.delegate = self;
    lyr.transform = t;  
    [animation setValue:@"grow" forKey:@"name"];
    [animation setValue:lyr forKey:@"layer"];
    [lyr addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I like the effect :-)

This would not be too useful if I wanted to query the state of a particular circle though? Although I suppose I could keep a reference to all existing layers and use those to query things like the layer's dimensions (should I want to handle collisions, for example)

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of ways to skin that cat. Take a look at CALayer`s `hitTest:` method. It uses the layer's rectangular bounds by default, but you could subclass CAShapeLayer for your expanding circle and provide a hitTest implementation that is smart about transparency/geometry.