# Get size of an expanding circle in a CABasicAnimation at any point in time

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, caanimation, cabasicanimation

I would like to know how I can get the diameter (or radius) of an expanding circle animation at a at any point in time during the animation. I will end up stoping the animation right after I get the size as well, but figure I couldn't stop and remove it form the layer until I get the size of the circle.

For an example of how the expanding circle animation is implemented, it is a variation on the implementation shown in the `addGrowingCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)point` method in the answer in the [iPhone Quartz2D render expanding circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241519/iphone-quartz2d-render-expanding-circle) question.

I have tried to check various values on the layers, animation, etc but can't seem to find anything.  I figure worse case I can attempt to make a best guess by taking the current time it is into its animation and use that to figure where it "should" be at based on its to and from size states.  This seems like overkill for what I would assume is a value that is incrementing someplace I can just get easily.

Update:

I have tried several properties on the Presentation Layer including the Transform which never seems to change all the values are always the same regardless of what size the circle is at the time checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is how you get the current state of the an animation while it is animating.

While Rob was close he left out two pieces of key information.

First from the layer.presentationLayer.subLayers you have to get the layer you are animating on, which for me is the only sub layer available.

Second, from this sub layer you cannot just access the transform directly you have to do it by valueForKeyPath to get transform.scale.x. I used x because its a circle and x and y are the same.

I then use this to calculate the size of the circle at the time of the based on the values used to create the Arc.

Comment: +1 This is useful. I'm not clear what you mean by "cannot just access the transform directly." Are you saying that -transform and -valueForKey:@"transform" are returning different things? Or do you mean that it's more convenient to get to the scale using the KVC call?

Answer (score -1):

I assume what you're trying to get to is the current `CATransform3D`, and that from that, you can get to your circle size.

What you want is the `layer.presentationLayer.transform`. See the `CALayer` docs for details on the presentationLayer. Also see the [Core Animation Rendering Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html).

Comment: I looked at that in debug mode with a break point and I didn't see any thing that provided the current size of the circles, there are actually very few things exposed on the transform. What property or method provides me with the diameter or radius? When that failed I tried using values on the presentationLayer like the bounds's width but it was always 0.  Which "layer" are you talking about the one that is part of the UIView or the CAShapeLayer I created in the method that creates and starts the animation?  Do I need to cast the transform to CATransform3D or something else?

Comment: There isn't going to be any variable anywhere that contains "the current radius." You're drawing a circle into a layer, and then you're scaling the layer with a transform. You'd have calculate the current radius by applying the current scaling factor. If you don't understand transforms, you probably want to back-up and make sure you understand the code you've copied. Start by reading the Core Animation Programming Guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: You are being condescending & presumptive. Instead of offering quick help which is what StackOverflow is about you are coming off as saying "I know how but I am not going to tell you because I took the time to learn by reading and going to school while obviously you are just an idiot who copies code so I will only point you to reading material and not answer your question." You don't know me and thanks for nothing. I know "enough" about animation and transforms to understand the code sample, I am still however am learning and I was hoping to get some quick help to solve a problem from SO.

Comment: Noted. Your followup questions did not seem to show familiarity with the Core Animation Programming Guide, and lacking that makes quick answers more dangerous than useful. Your own posted answer is insightful and helpful, so congratulations on working it through. I'm sorry my pointers weren't helpful in that.